# Pressure Drag on a 2D Aerofoil even when no Separation of the Boundary Layer?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, drag, aerodynamics, lift

So if a 2D aerofoil is subjected to potential flow, then there isn't a boundary layer separation at any point with the surface of the object, and hence pressure remains constant at the front and back of the aerofoil. Therefore, there is no pressure distribution and as form drag or pressure drag is caused by a pressure distribution, the pressure drag = 0, however, I have been told that pressure drag does not equal 0. Why is this the case?

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think the pressure is constant on a 2D airfoil? It certainly is not, even in potential flow, except for trivial cases!

Comment: @D.Halsey, Since there is no separation of the boundary layer, the pressure at the front and the back should be same, no?

Comment: You have a couple of misunderstandings:1-The pressure varies all along the surface, whether there is a boundary layer or not. 2. Boundary layers introduce  a front-to-back asymmetry in the pressure distributions, resulting in drag, whether there is separation or not.

Comment: In potential flow there is no boundary layer. Therefore, no separation, either. Regarding pressure: In potential flow you have two stagnation points, on in the front and the second in the back. Both experience stagnation pressure. Between both, pressure will vary greatly and only total pressure will be constant.

Comment: @PeterKämpf why would the pressure vary greatly, if there is no separtion of the boundary layer, shouldn't the pressure at the front and the back must stay constant? Thank you.

Comment: The air must flow around an obstacle and does this by speeding up. This reduces local pressure. Once the maximum thickness of the obstacle has passed, things revert back to normal. The pressure at the front and back is the same but **varies along the length of the obstacle**.

Comment: @PeterKämpf, ah right, and thsi variation of pressure or pressure distribution causes a drag force?

Comment: Only in combination with viscosity. See [d'Alembert's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_paradox).

Comment: @PeterKämpf yes, thank you this makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

In potential flow there is no boundary layer. Therefore, no separation, either. Regarding pressure: In potential flow you have two stagnation points, on in the front and the second in the back. Both experience stagnation pressure. Between both, pressure will vary greatly and only total pressure will be constant.

An airfoil presents an obstacle to the air and in order to flow around this obstacle, [it needs to speed up](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/56222/what-is-compressibility-drag/57430#57430). This reduces local pressure. Once the maximum thickness of the obstacle has passed, things revert back to normal. The pressure at the front and back is the same but varies along the length of the airfoil.

Drag will only appear in combination with viscosity. See [d'Alembert's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_paradox).